# How to create complex 3d shapes in css ? (duct tape band)

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to create a scotch tape band design on my website. I would like it to look almost like that : [image]

I designed yet the clean tape but I cannot manage to create the bendings (circled on the picture) properly.

this is what I have yet.

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.duct-tape {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: space-around;
    transform-origin: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.duct-tape:nth-of-type(1) {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateZ(-20deg);
}


.duct-tape:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateZ(30deg);
}

.duct-tape > .shadow {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   height: .3px;
   width: 50px;
   transform: rotateZ(-30deg) translateX(13px);
   border-radius: 100%;
   box-shadow: .1em .1em .25em rgb(130, 130, 0);
}

/* debug code */
.circle {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   border-radius: 100px;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   border: 2px solid lightblue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-60%, -60%);
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="duct-tape">
    <span>any text</span>
    <span>any text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="duct-tape">
    <span>any text</span>
    <span>any text</span>
    <span class="shadow"></span>
  </div>
  
  <!-- debug code -->
  <span class="circle"></span>
</body>
```

Yet I thought about create little shadow elements (class `shadow` in `duct-tape` in the snippet) that would act like the bendings. I thought about svg too, but it doesn't seem I can easily create such an svg. I know `css` packs up 3D transforms, could it help me or this is too specific to be properly done using `css 3D transforms` ? Any idea of easier ways to do it ?

Comment: You have to dive into Patterns and Filters: https://css-tricks.com/creating-patterns-with-svg-filters/

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at clip-path, rgba() colors and gradient.

here is a quick example to show the idea.

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}

span {
  --rt: 45deg;
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--ht, 400px);
  width: var(--wdt, 50px);
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, transparent 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 32%, transparent 33%), radial-gradient(circle at 60% 40%, transparent 15px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 17%, transparent 20%) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -200px -25px;
  transform: rotate(var(--rt));
    clip-path: polygon(1% 0%, 19% 1%, 30% 0%, 38% 0%, 48% 1%, 58% 3%, 62% 3%, 79% 3%, 73% 1%, 84% 0%, 87% 0%, 91% 4%, 92% 2%, 99% 0%, 96% 5%, 96% 20%, 100% 34%, 100% 46%, 99% 54%, 95% 57%, 87% 69%, 100% 77%, 100% 82%, 100% 89%, 100% 96%, 90% 99%, 76% 100%, 71% 97%, 63% 100%, 54% 99%, 51% 100%, 37% 98%, 34% 100%, 21% 99%, 17% 100%, 14% 98%, 10% 100%, 3% 98%, 3% 100%, 0% 85%, 4% 80%, 0% 74%, 4% 55%, 6% 45%, 3% 40%, 0% 34%, 6% 25%, 4% 16%, 1% 13%);
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  --rt: -45deg;
  --ht: 450px;
  background-size: 150% 200%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 13% 2%, 22% 0%, 28% 0%, 34% 2%, 46% 2%, 60% 2%, 69% 3%, 79% 1%, 80% 0%, 90% 0%, 93% 3%, 100% 4%, 99% 98%, 97% 100%, 87% 99%, 80% 100%, 74% 99%, 68% 100%, 60% 99%, 50% 100%, 43% 97%, 33% 96%, 31% 98%, 24% 99%, 20% 100%, 14% 98%, 9% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  --rt: -45deg;
  --wdt: 40px;
  --ht: 200px;
  left: 25%;
  background-size: 110% 200%;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  --rt:15deg;
  --wdt: 40px;
  --ht: 150px;
  left: 25%;
  background-size: 40% 50%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 13% 2%, 22% 0%, 28% 0%, 34% 2%, 46% 2%, 60% 2%, 69% 3%, 79% 1%, 80% 0%, 90% 0%, 93% 3%, 100% 4%, 99% 98%, 97% 100%, 87% 99%, 80% 100%, 74% 99%, 68% 100%, 60% 99%, 50% 100%, 43% 97%, 33% 96%, 31% 98%, 24% 99%, 20% 100%, 14% 98%, 9% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

gradient linear,radial and conic can be used via background and resized and repeated or not, clip-path can allow you to cut off some pieces . a usefull tool to help you https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

mask svg is also a possibility instead clip-path or mixed with.